# How do I cause Webstorm to automatically place the closing tag on the next line after auto-completing the tag?

Tags: html, webstorm

For the project I'm working on I like to keep almost all of my closing tags on separate lines instead of on the same line as the opening tag. This is true for most of the tags, not just .

For example:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="heading">
        Content....
    </div>
</div>
```

However in WebStorm, as soon as I press '>' to end the opening tag, the editor generates the closing tag (great!) but places it on the same line (boo). Ideally I would like WebStorm to place the closing tag on the line below, but return the carrot to just before the ending '>' of the opening tag so that I can add attributes to it. However, I think this is probably asking too much; I'll settle for just having the closing tag be automatically placed on the next line.

I'm still a bit new to HTML and am working through textbook examples. When copying code from a book or online source, it is really helpful for me to generate the outer structure of the elements before filling in the attributes and content. Far fewer typos and errors this way. My process is this.

1. Open the tag, including the ending '>'
2. Place the closing tag on the line below.
3. Return to the opening tag to fill in attributes.

Anyway to automate this in WS?

I've played around with the HTML CodeStyle settings, namely the "Insert new line before" and "Inline Elements" settings, but they don't seem to make a difference for what I'm doing.

Comment: [Enter] typestuff [enter] doesn't work?

Comment: It's an extra step, and I know it's small, but with the number of tags I'm writing it throws off my pace since I associate [enter] with wanting to be on the line below to type. Instead I want the closing tag to be on the line below, but the cursor to remain on the line of the opening tag, preferably before the closing '>'. Right now it's   '>'   -->   [enter]  --> [up] --> [right]  --> [right] -->  [space] --> [type attribute].  After writing this it seems kind of ridiculous ..... I should probably just change my coding style and type in attributes before adding the closing tag, but...{sigh}.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes it's challenging to let the software make things easier. Give it a try.